# hidden tables and fields are not available in powerbi dataflow

Tags: powerbi

I am creating DataFlow on the Azure Analysis Service. Some of the tables and fields in some of the tables are hidden. Those tables and fields are not available in the model list when I am trying to add tables to the dataflow. Is it related with my permission? I can see the Hidden tables and fields from my PowerBI desktop.

For example there a table, REASONS, with fields REASON_ID, REASON_NAME. REASON_ID is a hidded field. Both fields I can see from PowerBI desktop when I select View Hidden option. But the field REASON_ID is not available when I create a Dataflow for the same table.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "create a Dataflow for the same table"? Usually you create a Dataset from a Dataflow.

Comment: What I mean is when we create a dataflow, we need to select a Model and fields right. My problem when I am creating a Dataflow the hidden tables and fields are not available in the Model list.

Comment: So it's the same behaviour as with **Analyze in Excel** and I always found it helpful to not overload the end-user with temporary tables, but to provide a clean interface.

Comment: But I need all those fields and tables to set the relationship.

Comment: Then you need to ask the owner of the dataset. There's probably a reason why he restricted the access.